# Custom Type Qlist and Scope

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to append an object of type student containing a Qlist of QStrings to a Qlist of type students, I have verified that the Qstrings are being added to the student object at one stage, however they seem to be empty when I get to the code below;

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++){
                qDebug() << studentList.at(i).atindex(i);
```

Is shown at the bottom.

-**Listmanager.h**

```
#ifndef LISTMANAGER_H
#define LISTMANAGER_H
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class listManager: QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    listManager();
    listManager(QList<QString> list);
    QAbstractItemModel* listManager::getmodelview();
    QAbstractItemModel* listManager::getclassmodelView();
public:
    QStandardItemModel *courseModel = new QStandardItemModel(0,0);
    QStandardItemModel *classModel = new QStandardItemModel(0,0);

};

#endif // LISTMANAGER_H
```

-**relevent part of listmanager.cpp**

```
        student st;
        int count2 = 0;
         for (int i =6; i < list.size(); ++i){
            if(count2 < 6){
                st.appendtolist(list.at(i));
                count2++;
            }
            if(count2 == 6){
                count2 =0;
                studentList.append(st);
                st.showlist();
                st.clearlist();
            }
         }

        for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++){
            qDebug() << studentList.at(i).atindex(i);
```

-**student.cpp**

```
        #include "student.h"
        #include <QDebug>

        student::student()
        {
        }

        void student::appendtolist(QString item){
            list->append(item);
        }

        void student::showlist(){
            qDebug() << *list;
        }
        void student::clearlist(){
            list->clear();
        }

        QString student::atindex(int index)const {
             for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++){
                 if(index == i){
                     return list->at(i);
                 }
             }

             return "Not Good!";
        }
```

-**student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <QString>
#include <QList>

class student
{
public:
    QList<QString> *list = new QList<QString>();
    student();
    void student::appendtolist(QString item);
    void student::showlist();
    void student::clearlist();
    QString atindex(int index) const;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H
```

**Ouput:**

> "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not
>   Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!"
>   "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not Good!" "Not
>   Good!"

Comment: There is no need to allocate the list dynamically, it already uses dynamic allocation internally.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that.

Comment: You don't need to `QList<QString> *list = new QList<QString>();` instead `QList<QString> list;` suffices. You don't gain anything from doing that, and even lose a little, since it adds another level of indirection and memory usage and allocation overhead.

Comment: Also, might I ask what are you trying to achieve exactly in the code you labeled as "relevent part of listmanager.cpp"?

Comment: Thanks Ddrive, yes I was under the impression `QList<QString> *list = new QList<QString>();` was not needed, I was just fiddling. Sure, I have a big list of entries, e.g. name,data,id....,...,...  the entries are in groups of sixes.I am making sub lists and making those sub lists entries in the larger list. So index 0 of studentList is a list of 6 entries etc..

Answer (score 1):

It is entirelly pointless and even inefficient to allocate the list dynamically, use `QList<QString> list;` instead, change `list->` to `list.` and `*list` to `list`

You loop for no reason in `atindex()`, it is pointless looping through the list until `i` hits `index`, you can check if `index` is in the range of the list with a single expression.

```
QString student::atindex(int index) const {
    if (index < list.size()) return list.at(index); // index is in range
    else return "Not good!"; // index is out of range - no good
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if you know, how did changing those elements fix the code?

Comment: @user4217633 did it really fix it?

Comment: Partially, its giving me back some of the elements, not all of them. Sorry its not completely resolved.

Comment: @user4217633 - I didn't think it would solve it, just gave you a recommended practice advice. As I hinted in a previous comment, your "relevent part of listmanager.cpp" code is likely the culprit. But only from that segment of code I can't tell for sure what the problem is.